# Windows company laptop to detect if mouse is being moved by scripts rather than physically

Tags: windows, autokey

Can a company laptop detect if your mouse is being moved by a script? In other words, if I make a script (in any language) that moves the mouse in a random pattern to prevent the computer from auto-locking, is there a way for the company's systems to detect that the mouse is being moved by a script?

Comment: I used to work for the IT department of a large enterprise before retirement. Even if it were technically possible, implementing such kind of what-moved-the-mouse monitoring would be far beyond reasonable effort. But coded mouse wiggling is not the proper way to fight unwanted screen locking anyway. Did you ever notice that while you watch a video or follow an online meeting your screen doesn't lock, even if the lock timer has elapsed and you didn't touch kbd or mouse? The API allowing such magic is SetThreadExecutionState().

Comment: Thanks this is hugely helpful. In my case in the company laptop I have to access a virtual machine through a VPN to loop into the client's company workspace, and in that virtual machine I take zoom meetings. In the meeting on the virtual machine, if I do not move the mouse the laptop goes to lock screen. Maybe because the SetThreadExecutionState() you mention is not applicable if the zoom app is open from within a virtual machine accessed through VPN

Comment: But is it possible that in the laptop I start the process SetThreadExecutionState() from CLI?

Comment: SetThreadExecutionState() just affects the system where it is fired. Your host laptop doesn't know what happens within the VM, so it locks according to your company policy settings, even if Zoom within the VM keeps the VM desktop unlocked.
You need to fire SetThreadExecutionState() periodically on your host laptop to keep it unlocked. If you google for SetThreadExecutionState you may find free tools which are ready to go for exactly your purpose. If you have sufficient coding skills you can easily create your own tool.

Comment: My own implementation is basically just a 3-liner:

`FOREVER { SetThreadExecutionState( ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED + ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED + ES_CONTINUOUS ); Sleep( 5 * 60 * 1000 );  // every 5 minutes }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They may use heuristic analysis, behaviour-based detection, or endpoint security solutions that can recognize patterns indicative of scripted mouse movements.